# No me cargan las fuentes de google fonts en el navegador

Tags: html, css, fuentes

apenas estoy aprendiendo sobre html y css. Intente hacer un ejercicio, y para ello en el archivo html cargue unas fuentes de google fonts con link, y en el archivo css le puse la otra parte. Sin embargo al cargar la pagina del archivo html no carga la fuente. Estoy utilizando montserrat, ya utilice roboto y tampoco. Ayuda[image: Archivo css]

[image: Archivo html]

EL Código HTML es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"/>
</head>
```

El código css es

```
html { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Por alguna razon no se porque mi archivo de css se guarda con este simbolo de gato parece que no se esta conectando con el html.Lo cree desde la pestaña de file, new file ya que con la de archivo me dice New Untitled text file, no se como cambiar eso y que solo se haga el archivo cuando le de clic en esa opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tengo el problema de que si quiero abrir un nuevo archivo si le doy en el más me dice New Untitled text file en lugar de solo decirme new file y poder crear el archivo directo

[image: New Untitle text File]

Comment: No probaste agregando algun elemento como un div por ejemplo con un id, ponerle un texto y en el css agregarle la fuente con el id?

Comment: Ademas estas declarando dos veces la propiedad font-family en el mismo selector, por lo que solo se quedara con la ultima y esta deberia ser global para todos los elementos ya que html es el tag raiz de un documento HTML

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en la consola del navegador? Por favor pon el código como texto, no como imagen, pulsando en [edit].

Comment: infinit3Loop no he probado lo del div ya declare solo una vez el font family pero aun así no me aplica la fuente.

Comment: A.Cedano me pedia actualizar el navegador de firefox ya lo actualice pero aun asi no me toma en cuenta la fuente indicada

Comment: Comprueba que el nombre del archivo CSS coincida con el nombre dentro de la propiedad 'href' del tag <link>, comprueba que estén en el mismo directorio ambos archivos, por lo demás no se me ocurre nada, me funciona bien a mi.

Comment: Tal como ha dicho @A.Cedano, comprueba en el inspector del navegador (click derecho > inspeccionar y mira donde está el problema. Saludos